# Remove duplicates in list using Distinct

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove duplicate id's from a list on a browser I'm working on. The list is converted to array and then added to a richtextbox. This is needed for the generic bookmarking system I am working on. The issue is it scrapes duplicates. Even after I add distinct to the code.

```
string html = WebsCon2.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html); var playerIds = new List<string>();
var playerNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, '/link/profile-view.jsp?user=')]").Distinct();
foreach (var playerNode in playerNodes)
{
    string href = playerNode.Attributes["href"].Value;
    var parts = href.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (parts.Length > 1)
    {
        playerIds.Add(parts[1]);
    }
    string Target = string.Join("", playerIds.ToArray());
    PlayerID.Text = Target;
}
```

So is there another way I can remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Distinct` doesn't compare your nodes by their content. It compares them by reference. If you want distinct nodes by `InnerText` you can use:

```
var playerNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
            .SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, '/link/profile-view.jsp?user=')]")
            .GroupBy(node => node.InnerText)
            .Select(g => g.First());
```

Or you can use [`DistinctBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method from `MoreLINQ`:

```
var playerNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
            .SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, '/link/profile-view.jsp?user=')]")
            .DistinctBy(node => node.InnerText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `playerIds` as a `HashSet<string>` and then you are sure there will be no duplicates. That's the easy solution to your problem. Check the `HashSet` constructors to provide a comparer that will allow you to make sure you are case-sensitive/case-insensitive with the distinct strings (depending on your preference).

The `Distinct()` call you're making you can get rid of. This will not help you doing it the way you call it.